# C++ Chess Engine - Initialization of Magic Bitboard Attack Tables

Tags: c++, chess

I've just completed the generation of magic bitboard attack tables for bishops and rooks in my C++ chess engine.

## Main Questions

1. The functions `generateMagicNumbers()` and `populateAttackDatabase()` take 4 parameters, and `searchForMagicNumber()` takes 5. Is this too many? Is there a way to improve on this?
2. `calculateAttacks()` takes a function pointer as a parameter, and this function serves as a way for telling `calculateAttacks()` how to actually calculate the attacks, depending on if the piece is a bishop or rook. Is there anything wrong with this? It feels kinda like a code smell to me and was wondering if there is a way to improve on this? Ultimately I could combine `calculateBishopAttackBoard()` and `calculateRookAttackBoard()` into one function `calculateAttackBoard()`, and that would eliminate the need to pass these functions as parameters
3. `searchForMagicNumber()` takes a `square` parameter only to be used for debugging purposes. Is this acceptable?

Of course any and all feedback would be greatly appreciated!

## `magicbitboard.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "types.h"
#include "bitboard.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "constants.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

namespace magic_bitboards
{

struct HashInformation
{
    Bitboard blockerMask;
    u64 magicNumber;
    int shiftAmount;
};

extern HashInformation BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];
extern HashInformation ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];

// Bishops have between 32 and 512 unique possible blocker variations depending on the square
constexpr int LARGEST_AMOUNT_OF_BISHOP_BLOCKER_CONFIGURATIONS = 512;

// Rooks have between 1024 and 4096 unique possible blocker variations depending on the square
constexpr int LARGEST_AMOUNT_OF_ROOK_BLOCKER_CONFIGURATIONS = 4096;

constexpr int MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_BITS_FOR_BISHOP_HASHING = 3;
constexpr int MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_BITS_FOR_ROOK_HASHING = 6;

extern Bitboard BISHOP_ATTACKS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES][LARGEST_AMOUNT_OF_BISHOP_BLOCKER_CONFIGURATIONS];
extern Bitboard ROOK_ATTACKS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES][LARGEST_AMOUNT_OF_ROOK_BLOCKER_CONFIGURATIONS];

void init();

namespace
{

extern u64 BISHOP_MAGIC_NUMBERS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];
extern u64 ROOK_MAGIC_NUMBERS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];

// The number of set bits in the bishop blocker mask for each square
constexpr int NUMBER_OF_SET_BITS_IN_BISHOP_BLOCKER_MASK[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES] = {
    6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6,
};

// The number of set bits in the rook blocker mask for each square
constexpr int NUMBER_OF_SET_BITS_IN_ROOK_BLOCKER_MASK[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES] = {
    12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12,
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
    12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12,
};

// Define an alias for passing calculate<Piece>AttackBoard() as a parameter to another function
using calculateAttackBoardFunction = Bitboard (*)(const Square & square, const Bitboard & blockerVariation);

void initializeHashInformationEntries();

void generateBlockerMasks();

Bitboard calculateBishopBlockerMask(const Bitboard &bitboard);

Bitboard calculateRookBlockerMask(const Bitboard &bitboard);

std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> calculateBlockerVariations(HashInformation const * HASH_INFORMATION_TABLE);

std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> calculateAttacks(calculateAttackBoardFunction calculateAttackBoard,
                                                                              const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>,
                                                                              Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & blockerVariations);

void generateMagicNumbers(HashInformation * hashInformationTable,
                          const int minimumBitsRequiredForHashing,
                          const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & blockerVariations,
                          const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & attackBoards);

u64 searchForMagicNumber(const Square square,
                         const HashInformation & hashInformation,
                         const int minimumAmountOfBitsInLastByte,
                         const std::vector<Bitboard> & allBlockerVariations,
                         const std::vector<Bitboard> & attackBoards);

template <size_t rows, size_t columns>
void populateAttackDatabase(Bitboard (&attackDatabase)[rows][columns],
                            const HashInformation * hashInformationTable,
                            const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & blockerVariations,
                            const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & attackBoards);

int hashBlockerVariation(const Bitboard & blockerVariation, const u64 magicNumber, const int shiftAmount);

std::vector<Bitboard> enumerateSubmasks(Bitboard blockerMask);

Bitboard calculateBishopAttackBoard(const Square & square, const Bitboard & blockerVariation);

Bitboard calculateRookAttackBoard(const Square & square, const Bitboard & blockerVariation);

bool targetSquareIsBlocked(Bitboard targetSquare, Bitboard occupiedSquares);

Bitboard getPotentialBishopAttacks(const int square, const Bitboard &blockers);

} // anonymous namespace

} // namespace magic_bitboards
```

## `magicbitboard.cpp`

```
#include "magicbitboard.h"

namespace magic_bitboards
{

HashInformation BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];
HashInformation ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];
Bitboard BISHOP_ATTACKS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES][LARGEST_AMOUNT_OF_BISHOP_BLOCKER_CONFIGURATIONS];
Bitboard ROOK_ATTACKS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES][LARGEST_AMOUNT_OF_ROOK_BLOCKER_CONFIGURATIONS];

void init()
{
    initializeHashInformationEntries();
    generateBlockerMasks();

    std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> bishopBlockerVariations = calculateBlockerVariations(BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION);
    std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> rookBlockerVariations = calculateBlockerVariations(ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION);

    std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> bishopAttacks = calculateAttacks(calculateBishopAttackBoard, bishopBlockerVariations);
    std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> rookAttacks = calculateAttacks(calculateRookAttackBoard, rookBlockerVariations);

    std::cout << "Searching for bishop magics, this could take up to 30 seconds... " << std::endl;
    generateMagicNumbers(BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION, MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_BITS_FOR_BISHOP_HASHING, bishopBlockerVariations, bishopAttacks);
    std::cout << "DONE." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Searching for rook magic numbers, this could take up to 30 seconds... " << std::endl;
    generateMagicNumbers(ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION, MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_BITS_FOR_ROOK_HASHING, rookBlockerVariations, rookAttacks);
    std::cout << "DONE." << std::endl;

    populateAttackDatabase(BISHOP_ATTACKS, BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION, bishopBlockerVariations, bishopAttacks);
    populateAttackDatabase(ROOK_ATTACKS, ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION, rookBlockerVariations, rookAttacks);
}

namespace
{

u64 BISHOP_MAGIC_NUMBERS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];
u64 ROOK_MAGIC_NUMBERS[Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];

void initializeHashInformationEntries()
{
    for (int square = 0; square < Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; square++)
    {
        HashInformation bishopEntry;
        HashInformation rookEntry;

        BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION[square] = bishopEntry;
        ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION[square] = rookEntry;
    }
}

void generateBlockerMasks()
{
    for (int square = 0; square < Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; square++)
    {
        Bitboard squareBitboard(square);

        // Calculate the blocker mask for each piece on this square
        BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION[square].blockerMask = calculateBishopBlockerMask(squareBitboard);
        ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION[square].blockerMask = calculateRookBlockerMask(squareBitboard);

        // Store the shift amount to be used in the hash function
        BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION[square].shiftAmount = BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION[square].blockerMask.numberOfSetBits();
        ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION[square].shiftAmount = ROOK_HASHING_INFORMATION[square].blockerMask.numberOfSetBits();
    }
}

std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> calculateBlockerVariations(HashInformation const * hashInformationTable)
{
    std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> blockerVariations;
    for (int square = 0; square < Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; square++)
    {
        blockerVariations[square] = enumerateSubmasks(hashInformationTable[square].blockerMask);
    }

    return blockerVariations;
}

std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> calculateAttacks(calculateAttackBoardFunction calculateAttackBoard, const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & blockerVariations)
{
    std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> attacks;

    for (int square = 0; square < Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; square++)
    {
        int numberOfBlockerVariations = blockerVariations[square].size();
        std::vector<Bitboard> attackBoards(numberOfBlockerVariations);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlockerVariations; i++)
        {
            attackBoards[i] = calculateAttackBoard((Square)square, blockerVariations[square][i]);
        }

        attacks[square] = attackBoards;
    }
    
    return attacks;
}

void generateMagicNumbers(HashInformation * hashInformationTable,
                          const int minimumBitsRequiredForHashing,
                          const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & blockerVariations,
                          const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & attackBoards)
{
    for (int square = 0; square < Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; square++)
    {
        hashInformationTable[square].magicNumber = searchForMagicNumber((Square)square, hashInformationTable[square], minimumBitsRequiredForHashing, blockerVariations[square], attackBoards[square]);
    }
}

u64 searchForMagicNumber(const Square square, const HashInformation & hashInformation, const int minimumAmountOfBitsInLastByte, const std::vector<Bitboard> & allBlockerVariations, const std::vector<Bitboard> & attackBoards)
{
    Bitboard tempAttackDatabase[LARGEST_AMOUNT_OF_ROOK_BLOCKER_CONFIGURATIONS];
    const int numberOfBlockerVariations = allBlockerVariations.size();
    u64 magicNumberCandidate;
    bool foundMagicNumber = false;

    while (foundMagicNumber == false)
    {
        bool currentMagicNumberIsValid = true;

        // Reset the attack database to all empty boards
        std::fill(std::begin(tempAttackDatabase), std::end(tempAttackDatabase), Bitboard(constants::UNIVERSE));
        
        // Calculate a magic number candidate for this square
        magicNumberCandidate = utils::getSparselyPopulatedRandom64BitInteger();

        // Verify the magic number effeciently maps bits from the blocker mask to the most significant bit positions of the product
        if (Bitboard( (hashInformation.blockerMask * magicNumberCandidate) & 0xFF00000000000000ULL ).numberOfSetBits() < minimumAmountOfBitsInLastByte) { continue; }

        // Hash each blocker variation and attempt to store the attack boards
        for (int i = 0; (i < numberOfBlockerVariations) && currentMagicNumberIsValid; i++)
        {
            int hashedIndex = hashBlockerVariation(allBlockerVariations[i], magicNumberCandidate, hashInformation.shiftAmount);

            // Check if this spot in the database is empty
            if (tempAttackDatabase[hashedIndex].getBoard() == constants::UNIVERSE) { tempAttackDatabase[hashedIndex] = attackBoards[i]; }

            // If the collision gives us the same attack board, then we're fine
            // If the collision gives us a different attack board, search for a new magic number 
            else if (tempAttackDatabase[hashedIndex].getBoard() != attackBoards[i].getBoard()) { currentMagicNumberIsValid = false; }
        }

        // If we made it through the previous for loop with no collisions then we found a magic number
        if (currentMagicNumberIsValid) { foundMagicNumber = true; }
    }

    #if DEBUG
    if (foundMagicNumber)
    {
        std::cout << "(Square " << square << ") FOUND magic number: " << magicNumberCandidate << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "(Square " << square << ") ERROR, no magic number found" << magicNumberCandidate << std::endl;
    }
    #endif

    return magicNumberCandidate;
}

int hashBlockerVariation(const Bitboard & blockerVariation, const u64 magicNumber, const int shiftAmount)
{
    return (blockerVariation * magicNumber) >> (Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES - shiftAmount);
}

template <size_t rows, size_t columns>
void populateAttackDatabase(Bitboard (&attackDatabase)[rows][columns],
                            const HashInformation * hashInformationTable,
                            const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & blockerVariations,
                            const std::array<std::vector<Bitboard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> & attackBoards)
{
    for (int square = 0; square < Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; square++)
    {
        const HashInformation & hashInfo = hashInformationTable[square];
        int numberOfBlockerVariations = blockerVariations[square].size();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlockerVariations; i++)
        {
            int hashedIndex = hashBlockerVariation(blockerVariations[square][i], hashInfo.magicNumber, hashInfo.shiftAmount);
            attackDatabase[square][hashedIndex] = attackBoards[square][i];
        }
    }
}

std::vector<Bitboard> enumerateSubmasks(Bitboard blockerMask)
{
    /*
     * This solved problem is also known as: enumerate all submasks of a bitmask.
     * Here is a link with some explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-submasks-of-a-given-mask/
     * One with better explanation: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/all-submasks.html
     */
    std::uint16_t numberOfBlockerVariations = pow(2, blockerMask.numberOfSetBits());
    std::vector<Bitboard> allBlockerVariations(numberOfBlockerVariations);

    std::uint16_t i = 0;
    for (u64 blockerVariation = blockerMask.getBoard(); blockerVariation; blockerVariation = (blockerVariation - 1) & blockerMask.getBoard())
    {
        allBlockerVariations[i] = blockerVariation;
        i++;
    }

    return allBlockerVariations;
}

Bitboard calculateBishopAttackBoard(const Square & square, const Bitboard & blockerVariation)
{
    Bitboard attackBoard;
    Bitboard squareBitboard(square);

    int numberOfMovesNorthEast = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, NORTH_EAST);
    int numberOfMovesNorthWest = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, NORTH_WEST);
    int numberOfMovesSouthEast = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, SOUTH_EAST);
    int numberOfMovesSouthWest = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, SOUTH_WEST);

    // TODO: maybe we can implement a function like the following?
    // attackBoard |= calculateAttacksInDirection(NORTH_EAST, numberOfMovesNorthEast, squareBitboard, blockerVariation);

    // Attacks to the north east
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesNorthEast; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * NORTH_EAST);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }

    // Attacks to the north west
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesNorthWest; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * NORTH_WEST);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }

    // Attacks to the south east
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesSouthEast; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * SOUTH_EAST);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }

    // Attacks to the south west
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesSouthWest; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * SOUTH_WEST);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }

    return attackBoard;
}

Bitboard calculateRookAttackBoard(const Square & square, const Bitboard & blockerVariation)
{
    Bitboard attackBoard;
    Bitboard squareBitboard(square);

    int numberOfMovesNorth = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, NORTH);
    int numberOfMovesSouth = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, SOUTH);
    int numberOfMovesEast = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, EAST);
    int numberOfMovesWest = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, WEST);

    // TODO: maybe we can implement a function like the following?
    // attackBoard |= calculateAttacksInDirection(NORTH_EAST, numberOfMovesNorthEast, squareBitboard, blockerVariation);

    // Attacks to the north
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesNorth; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * NORTH);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }

    // Attacks to the south
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesSouth; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * SOUTH);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }

    // Attacks to the east
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesEast; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * EAST);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }

    // Attacks to the west
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfMovesWest; i++)
    {
        Bitboard targetSquare = utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(squareBitboard, i * WEST);
        if (targetSquareIsBlocked(targetSquare, blockerVariation)) { break; }
        else { attackBoard |= targetSquare; }
    }
}

bool targetSquareIsBlocked(Bitboard targetSquare, Bitboard occupiedSquares)
{
    return ( (targetSquare & occupiedSquares).numberOfSetBits() == 1 );
}

Bitboard calculateBishopBlockerMask(const Bitboard & bitboard)
{
    Bitboard potentialBlockersToTheBishop;
    Square square = static_cast<Square>(bitboard.findIndexLSB());

    // This is for magic bitboards, subtract 1 since the edge of the board isn't considered a blocking square
    int numberOfMovesNorthEast = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, NORTH_EAST) - 1;
    int numberOfMovesNorthWest = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, NORTH_WEST) - 1;
    int numberOfMovesSouthEast = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, SOUTH_EAST) - 1;
    int numberOfMovesSouthWest = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, SOUTH_WEST) - 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesNorthEast; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheBishop |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * NORTH_EAST);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesNorthWest; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheBishop |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * NORTH_WEST);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesSouthEast; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheBishop |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * SOUTH_EAST);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesSouthWest; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheBishop |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * SOUTH_WEST);
    }

    return potentialBlockersToTheBishop;
}

Bitboard calculateRookBlockerMask(const Bitboard &bitboard)
{
    Bitboard potentialBlockersToTheRook;
    Square square = static_cast<Square>(bitboard.findIndexLSB());

    // This is for magic bitboards, subtract 1 since the edge of the board isn't considered a blocking square
    int numberOfMovesNorth = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, NORTH) - 1;
    int numberOfMovesSouth = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, SOUTH) - 1;
    int numberOfMovesEast = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, EAST) - 1;
    int numberOfMovesWest = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, WEST) - 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesNorth; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheRook |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * NORTH);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesSouth; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheRook |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * SOUTH);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesEast; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheRook |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * EAST);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMovesWest; i++)
    {
        potentialBlockersToTheRook |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * WEST);
    }

    return potentialBlockersToTheRook;
}

} // anonymous namespace

} // namespace magic_bitboards
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> 1. The functions `generateMagicNumbers()` and `populateAttackDatabase()` take 4 parameters, and `searchForMagicNumber()` takes 5. Is this too many? Is there a way to improve on this?

Sometimes it just is necessary to have that many parameters. However, in this case we can improve things. First, prefer to `return` data instead of passing an out-pointer as a parameter. Second, maybe there is a way to group related data into a `struct`. For example:

```
struct Variations {
    std::array<std::vector<BitBoard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> blockers;
    std::array<std::vector<BitBoard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> attacks;
};

std::array<HashInformation, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES>
generateMagicNumbers(const int minimumBitsForHashing, const Variations& variations) {
    std::array<HashInformation, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES> hashInformationTable;

    for (std::size_t square = 0; square < hashInformationTable.size(); ++square)
    {
        auto& info = hashInformationTable[square];
        info[square].magicNumber = searchForMagicNumber(square, info, minimumBitsRequiredForHashing, variations[square]);
    }

    return hashInformationTable;
}
```

> 2. `calculateAttacks()` takes a function pointer as a parameter, and this function serves as a way for telling `calculateAttacks()` how to actually calculate the attacks, depending on if the piece is a bishop or rook. Is there anything wrong with this? It feels kinda like a code smell to me and was wondering if there is a way to improve on this? Ultimately I could combine `calculateBishopAttackBoard()` and `calculateRookAttackBoard()` into one function `calculateAttackBoard()`, and that would eliminate the need to pass these functions as parameters

Passing a function pointer is perfectly fine! It makes the code more modular and avoids some code duplication. Compilers are also great at inlining, so it probably won't affect performance at all.

3. `searchForMagicNumber()` takes a `square` parameter only to be used for debugging purposes. Is this acceptable?

It might be handy for debugging, but it makes the code more complex than necessary. I would avoid it. Also consider that you can have the caller print the debug message; they know which square it is and they get the `magicNumberCandidate` from the return value.

## Code formatting

Avoid putting multiple statements on one line. Especially since your variable names are quite long, you have to scroll a lot to see the body of `if` and `else`-statements in your code.

## Avoid repetitive code

There is quite a lot of code duplication in your program. Apart from having to type in everything, having to maintain it, it also makes it easy for copy&paste errors to creep in. Try to find ways to avoid repeating the same thing. There are various ways to do this. Creating helper functions is one way, using a more data-drive approach is another. Consider for example:

```
Bitboard calculateRookBlockerMask(const Bitboard &bitboard)
{
    Bitboard potentialBlockersToTheRook;
    auto square = static_cast<Square>(bitboard.findIndexLSB());

    for (auto direction: {NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST}) {
        int numberOfMoves = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, direction) - 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMoves; i++) {
            potentialBlockersToTheRook |= utils::shiftCurrentSquareByDirection(bitboard, i * direction);
        }
    }

    return potentialBlockersToTheRook;
}
```

You can also avoid repeating long type names by using more `auto`, or creating type aliases. For example:

```
using BitBoardArray = std::array<std::vector<BitBoard>, Square::NUMBER_OF_SQUARES>;

BitBoardArray calculateBlockVariations(…);

void init() {
    …
    auto bishopBlockerVariations = calculateBlockerVariations(BISHOP_HASHING_INFORMATION);
    …
}
```

## Avoid using floating points unnecessarily

`pow()` always works on and returns a floating point number. However, if you just want to raise two to the power of something, you can instead shift the integer 1 by the same amount. So:

```
std::uint16_t numberOfBlockerVariations = 1 << blockerMask.numberOfSetBits();
```

## Prefer using the standard [fixed-width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

I see you use `std::uint16_t` in one place, but `u64` in some others. I recommend you don't define your own types, but stick to the ones from the standard library. Especially if you define them incorrectly, like like:

```
using u64 = unsigned long;
```

Which is wrong depending on the platform you are compiling for.

If you want to make an alias, then in this case it might be better to name it after what it is being used for: magic numbers, so perhaps `Magic` or `MagicNumber`?

## You can let the initialization be done at compile time

The calculation of the bitboards can be done at compile time. To do this, make sure all the functions involved in it are [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). How easy this is depends on the version of C++ you are using. Since C++20 there is also `constinit` and `consteval` that can be used to force compile-time evaluation and initialization.

Comment: Hey thanks so much, this is amazing feedback and exactly what I was hoping for. I will certainly incorporate this. For the line `int numberOfMoves = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, direction) - 1;`, either I could turn the `-1` into a function-scoped `const` called `edgeSquare`, or I could change the distance calculation function to `int numberOfMoves = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, direction, false);` where `false` is the argument for the function parameter `includeEdgeSquare`. Do you have any thoughts on one over the other?

Comment: I would rewrite it to: `int distanceFromEdge = utils::calculateDistanceFromEdgeOfBoard(square, direction); for (int i = 1; i < distanceFromEdge; i++) {…}`. Maybe `distanceToEdge` would be an even better name, since you are going outward from the position of `square` to the edge in that `for`-loop.

Comment: Great idea, thanks so much